# How do I use the Schwarzschild metric to calculate space curvature and time curvature seperately?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, curvature

I want to understand the math behind the idea that around Earth time dilation accounts for 99.99% of gravity, while around a black hole it only accounts for 50% of gravity while space curvature accounts for the other 50%.  I think it can be shown with the first two terms of the Schwarzschild metric, but I can't figure out how.  Can you give some guidance on how I use the SM to show this discrepancy?  Or to put it in a different way; why — using the SM — does space curvature grow at such a rapid rate while time dilation does not when near a black hole?

Comment: *the idea* Whose idea, stated where?

Comment: @Ghoster   Take a look at your comment to my same idea in this posting https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/738032/are-photons-affected-by-temporal-gravity?noredirect=1#comment1652197_738032      I have read this idea several times. I'll try to find a reference for you.

Comment: The percentages you are quoting are wrong. Gravity is a consequence of the time curvature and has nothing to do with the space curvature. So gravity is 100% (gradient of) the time dilation for the Earth and for a black hole. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellis_wormhole - “*in space-time, the curvature of space has nothing to do with gravity (the 'curvature of time’, one could say)*”

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I quite dislike this particular turn of phrase - there is no meaningful sense in which curvature can be split into temporal and spatial parts.  We can talk about pure spatial curvature in the sense that we can foliate a $d$-dimensional spacetime into spacelike leaves $\Sigma_t$, each of which constitutes a $(d-1)$-dimensional Riemannian manfold. Each leaf inherits a Riemannian metric $\gamma$ from the pseudo-Riemannian metric $g$ of the full spacetime, and so we can talk about its inherited Riemann/Ricci tensors.

However, this is not really an intrinsic property of the full spacetime - a different foliation will result in different leaves with different curvatures.  More to the point, even in those situations where we can write the full spacetime as $\mathcal M = \mathbb R \times \Sigma$, a 1-dimensional manifold has no intrinsic curvature and therefore it doesn't make sense to talk about the "curvature of time."

What one presumably means when talking about this is the following.  If we consider the radial geodesic equation in Schwarzschild coordinates and assume only radial motion, we obtain the following equation (the dot denotes differentiation with respect to the proper time):

$$\ddot r + \Gamma^r_{\beta \nu} \dot x^\beta \dot x^\nu = 0 $$
$$\implies \ddot r =  -\Gamma^r_{tt} (c\dot t) ^2 - \Gamma^r_{r r} \dot r^2  - 2 \Gamma^r_{t r} (c\dot t) \dot r$$
Recall the formula for the Christoffel symbols:
$$\Gamma ^\mu_{\beta\nu} = \frac{1}{2} g^{\mu\rho} \big( \partial_\beta g_{\rho \nu} + \partial_\nu g_{\beta \rho} - \partial_\rho g_{\beta \nu}\big)$$
$$\implies \matrix{\Gamma^r_{tt} = \frac{1}{2} g^{rr} \big(\partial_t g_{rr} + \partial_t g_{rr} - \partial_r g_{tt}\big) = -\frac{1}{2}\big(1+\frac{2\Phi}{c^2}\big) \big(2\frac{\phi'}{c^2}\big)\\
\Gamma^r_{rr} = \frac{1}{2} g^{rr}\big(\partial_r g_{rr} + \partial_r g_{rr} - \partial_r g_{rr}\big)= \frac{1}{2}\big(1+\frac{2\Phi}{c^2}\big) \frac{-2\Phi'/c^2}{\big(1+\frac{2\Phi}{c^2}\big)^2}\\
\Gamma^r_{tr} = \frac{1}{2}g^{rr}\big(\partial_t g_{rr} +\partial_r g_{tr} - \partial_r g_{tr}\big) = 0 }$$
where $\Phi(r) = -GM/r$ is the Newtonian gravitational potential. After some simplification, the radial geodesic equation becomes

$$\ddot r = -\left(1+\frac{2\Phi}{c^2}\right)\frac{\Phi'}{c^2}\left(c^2\dot t^2 + \frac{\dot r^2}{\left(1+\frac{2\Phi}{c^2}\right)}\right)$$
$$= -\Phi'\left(1+\frac{2\Phi}{c^2}\right)\left(\dot t^2  + \frac{\dot r^2/c^2}{1+\frac{2\Phi}{c^2}}\right)$$

From the line element,
$$\mathrm d\tau^2 = \left(1+\frac{2\Phi}{c^2}\right) \mathrm dt^2 - \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{2\Phi}{c^2}\right)} \mathrm dr^2$$
$$\implies \dot t^2 = \frac{1 + \frac{\dot r^2}{(1+2\Phi/c^2)}}{1+\frac{2\Phi}{c^2}}$$
and so finally
$$\ddot r = -\Phi'\left( 1 + \frac{2\dot r^2/c^2}{1+\frac{2\Phi}{c^2}}\right)$$

I *assume* that the author of your statement is referring to the relative magnitudes of the terms in this expression.

Comment: Can you clarify in the final expression how the "1" term is more related to time while the other term is more related to space?

Comment: I do recall it being said that the faster an object's speed, the more it is moving in space and the less it is moving in time.  So perhaps that relates to the fact that when $(\dot r/c)^2$<<1, the second term is << the first term

Comment: @RC_23 Going back to the line element, note that $\frac{\dot r^2}{c^2} / (1+2\Phi/c^2) = (1+2\Phi/c^2)\dot t^2 - 1$. When the $\dot r$ term is small, the $\dot t$ term is close to $1$; when the $\dot r$ term approaches $1$, the $\dot t$ term approaches $2$.

Comment: If I look at your last expression, in light of my question, the most important part seems to be the 2r.^2 in the numerator.  This indicates that the entire value of the formula grows very rapidly as the warping of space grows. And of course we know that the warping of space grows very rapidly near the event horizon.  Is this a correct interpretation?  If so, is it correct to say that time dilation does not grow at this same rapid rate as we near the event horizon?  So we have the answer to my question?

Comment: @foolishmuse Approaching the black hole's event horizon means taking the limit $2\Phi/c^2 \rightarrow -1$. Given any value for $2\Phi/c^2$ in the interval $(-1,0)$, you can compute the time dilation factor for a stationary observer ($\mathrm dt = \mathrm d\tau/(1+2\Phi/c^2)$), which clearly grows without bound as you approach the horizon. I don't really know what you mean by "the warping of space."

Comment: Warping of space would be the actual length down a radial to an outside observer, compared to the length derived by dividing the circumference by 2pi.

Comment: @foolishmuse I see.  Well, the time dilation factor and the "spatial" factor you describe are the same, in fact, so I'm not sure that's the answer you're looking for.

Comment: *And of course we know that the warping of space grows very rapidly near the event horizon.* Curvature invariants are smooth at the horizon and do *not* grow very rapidly there. For example, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kretschmann_scalar).

Comment: I guess that's not the answer I expected, but if that's the answer then that's the answer.